# AS3 Targeting Unnamed Timeline Instances

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there any way to control nested **MovieClip** instances placed on the timeline without naming them through the Properties panel? Are there any unique identifiers I can refer to?

Using instance names (like instance33, instance12, etc.) doesn't help since names are just properties, but how about references like sprite187_27 (as returned by `trace(this)` inside a MovieClip on the TimeLine)?

*(Using ActionScript3, Automatically declare stage instances disabled)*

Comment: Okay, using unique classnames does the trick apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `[object sprite187_27]` is enough in identification, you can just loop through all the objects in your root timeline, like this:

```
var l:int = this.stage.numChildren;
for (var i:int = 0; i < l; i++)
{
    var instance:DisplayObject = this.getChildAt(i);
    trace(instance.toString()); // will output [object _whatever_]
}
```

Looping recursively just means checking if `instance.numChildren > 0`.

Comment: I was wondering if there's a way to get a reference to any nested MovieClip instance without giving it a name or specifying a class name, using only what the swf can give you at run-time- like those dynamically generated classes stored in the SwfName_fla package. But thanks for your answer, I will make use of the information you offered.